# Python Fitting polynomial to natural log, then reversing the transformation back into non-log space?

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting, smoothing, logarithm

I'm trying to create a smooth function to represent some data I am working with. Trouble is the data is pretty noisy, and simply using the least squares method to create a polynomial line of best fit does not come out that well.

```
polynomial = np.polyfit(df.x,df.y)
```

Doing some digging, apparently for this sort of thing some people first transform their input data into its natural log, which produces a nicer curve.

```
df['y']=np.log(df['y'])
lop_polynomial = np.polyfit(df.x,df.y)
```

And lo and behold it seems to work. When I turn this polynomial into a function and graph a bunch of points (by just taking e^x of the output), it looks like the kind of thing I want;

```
log_polynomial =np.poly1d(put_log_polynomial)

x_values = np.arange(0, 100,.01)
plt.plot(
    x_values,
    np.exp(log_polynomial (x_values ))
```

However, this requires me to transform the input data into log data, then find a polynomial of best fit, then turn that polynomial into a function, then turn that function into a bunch of discrete points, then make another polynomial of best fit around those points. Because this is something I am going to run a lot of times that's a lot of extra steps.

Is there a way to take a polynomial that I got using log inputs and transform it back into non-log space without manually doing an exponent on all of the inputs to get discrete points then trying to create a line of best fit for those points in non-log space?

---

**edit*** here is some more background on my use case. I have a set of discrete points that form a curve. The second derivative of this curve contains important information that I want to extract cleanly, but if I take the second derivative without modification it ends up very noisy, over-interpreting small kinks in the curve as huge rough spikes in the second derivative.

I have tried various things to smooth out the smooth out the curve, but all the other ones I've tried either failed to adequately address the noise or disrupted the inherent signal I am trying to isolate. Here's what I've tried so far:

Least squares line of best fit in non-log space

```
polynomial = np.polyfit(df.x,df.y)
```

1 dimensional gaussian filter

```
scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d(df.y, 3)
```

Cubic spline

```
t,c,k=scipy.interpolate.splrep(df.x,df.y,k=3)
```

B-spline

```
spline = scipy.interpolate.BSpline(t, c, k, extrapolate=False)
```

The reason I am trying to log transform it before finding the polynomial of best fit is because I found some research papers that use this method of interpolation for the exact use case I am working on and when I test it on my data it seems to work well.

---

***edit2**
As @NickODell astutely pointed out, there are a lot of potential polynomials that cannot be transformed back to non log space and still represent themselves in the python polynomial format of a list of coefficients for x to the power of integers. So that makes turning the log space polynomial back into a polynomial in non log space directly effectively impossible as far as I can tell.

What I really want though is the second derivative of my input data that is free of noise and retains all the signal. I was hopeful that I might be able to do this by transoforming the log space polynomial directly back to non-log space and deriving it directly, but apparently that's not going to be possible. However, it could still be represented as a function that I can derive using np.gradient, which would effectively allow the same thing. But I'm less confident this would actually be significantly increase the efficiency of the program. I'll try messing around with some profiling and see if I can get a handle on how large a deal this is.

***edit3** I want to thank @jlandercy and @Nick ODell for their clear and thorough answers. I wish I could select both of them as the answer.

Comment: Have you considered using Bayesian methods or just plain ole regularization? You can always use Ridge/Lasso/Elastic Net methods plus cross-validation to determine the best generalizing method. This would avoid this log-space transformation approach

Comment: Also, what is your use case? If you just need a smooth curve you can always just perform a smoothing routine or use a Generalized Additive Model i.e. spline regression?

Comment: @rsenne I added some more context to the original question. Hope that clears things up. I listed the methods that I have tried so far, but I could of course try some more and see if they work better for me than the ones I've tried so far. If there's a good method you think I should test please let me know and I will give it a try.

Comment: Can you clarify something for me? It seems like it would make sense to take the log of the y variable before fitting, then fit, then take the exp of the output of the polynomial. But this is taking the log of x and doing an exp on the output, which seems like it should cause the y value to be wildly wrong. Are you sure you're meant to be logging x and not y?

Comment: `Because this is something I am going to run a lot of times that's a lot of extra steps.` Is the concern the performance or complexity? From a performance perspective, the `np.exp()` and `np.log()` are really fast - they are about 60x faster than `np.polyfit()` on my computer, so I'm not sure it really makes sense to worry about them.

Comment: @NickODell Oh you're definitely right about logging y that's what I'm actually doing. My actual code looks somewhat different than this, but I rewrote it to put in this thread to be more straightforward. In actuallity I am logging y and not x.

Comment: @NickODell As for performance, I haven't actually done any profiling my code yet, so I'm not certain of how the performance is impacted. I just thought there may be a straightforward answer to this problem that someone knows. But it's not the np log and exp that concern me in terms of time, it's creating a polynomial of best fit using that polynomial to create a bunch of discrete points (that I then take the exponent of) then using those points to create a new polynomial then differentiating that polynomial. I thought there must be a way to go straight from log_polynomial to non_log_polynomial

Comment: How do you handle negative value for polynomial when you apply log?

Comment: I'm not sure there's always an equivalent non log polynomial. Imagine you fit the equation y=2.5x to the logged data. The non logged equivalent is y=x^2.5, which can't be written as a polynomial with only integer powers.

Comment: @jlandercy do you mean when I run df['y']=np.log(df['y']) to get the log of my y values? My input y values are positive by definition, they would never be negative in the first place.

Comment: @NickODell that's actually a great point, at least given the structure python uses to define polynomials as lists of integer values. So transforming it as a polynomial may not be possible after all. Still, transforming it into a function that I can take the second derivative of using something like np.gradient without having to create a bunch of discrete points and interpolating them into a function is very likely possible, but the question of what kind of benefit that would provide is worth considering seriously. I'll edit the post again to provide even more context.

Comment: It's very common to transform data into a space that better fits the model used.  Just write a function or two to do the transform/its reverse and use them when needed.  The actual model fitting will almost certainly take more time, and calling your functions should be convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your requirements, you want:

- Apply log transform on `y` axis;
- Fit polynomial data with huge noise;
- Predict values at new `x` points;
- Take second derivative of fitted curve;
- Automatize the process that must be performed multiple times.

Sklearn is a perfect package to perform such operations through `Pipeline`s.

First we create some polynomial noisy data:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50).reshape(-1, 1)
P = np.poly1d([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10])
y = P(x[:, 0])
n = 0.5 * np.random.randn(y.size)
yn = y + n
```

#### Simple regression

As a baseline, we create a pipeline to linearly regress polynomial from your data:

```
pipeline_lin = Pipeline([
    ("transformer", PolynomialFeatures(5)),
    ("model", LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))
])
```

And fit to dataset:

```
pipeline_lin.fit(x, y)

pipeline_lin["model"].coef_
# array([10.0226118 ,  1.51830909,  2.23638955,  2.91665499,  5.99904944, 7.88614861])
```

#### Log Transform

If you wish to apply logarithmic transformation on target (`y` axis, indeed it requires positiveness) we can change the pipeline for:

```
pipeline_log = Pipeline([
    ("transformer", PolynomialFeatures(5)),
    ("model",
         TransformedTargetRegressor(
             regressor=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False),
             func=np.log,
             inverse_func=np.exp
         )
    )
])
pipeline_log.fit(x, yn)

pipeline_log["model"].regressor_.coef_
# array([ 2.2901081 ,  0.15049063,  0.46685674,  0.32678866, -0.12522207, 0.34130133])
```

Indeed coefficients are not directly related to the original polynomial as we applied the log transformation.

Now we can predict new target values for other features without having the need to care about the forward and back log transform:

```
xlin = np.linspace(-1, 1, 200).reshape(-1, 1)
yh_lin = pipeline_lin.predict(xlin)
yh_log = pipeline_log.predict(xlin)

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(x, yn, marker=".", label="Data")
axe.plot(xlin, yh_lin, label="Linear")
axe.plot(xlin, yh_log, label="Log Linear")
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
```

[image]

#### Automation

The process can be repeated multiple times, simply chaining `fit` and `predict`:

```
# Iterate datasets:
for i in range(10):
    x = ...   # Select X data
    yn = ...  # Select Y data
    # Fit and predict:
    yhat = pipeline_log.fit(x, yn).predict(xlin)
```

#### Alternative

If you don't know the polynomial order and don't require the fit to be a polynomial regression (eg. you just want to predict plausible values), then Gaussian Process can be a good alternative:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

pipeline_gpr = Pipeline([
    ("model",
         TransformedTargetRegressor(
             regressor=GaussianProcessRegressor(
                 kernel=1.0*RBF(),
                 alpha=0.01
             ),
             func=np.log,
             inverse_func=np.exp
         )
    )
])
```

[image]

#### Taking second derivative

##### Numerically

A potential candidate to estimate second derivative is `savgol_filter` from `scipy`:

```
from scipy import signal

dx = xlin[1,0] - xlin[0,0]
yh_lin_d2 = signal.savgol_filter(yh_lin, 15, 3, deriv=2, delta=dx)
yh_log_d2 = signal.savgol_filter(yh_log, 15, 3, deriv=2, delta=dx)
yh_gpr_d2 = signal.savgol_filter(yh_gpr, 15, 3, deriv=2, delta=dx)
```

[image]

Caution, taking the derivative (or even worse the second derivative) of a fit is not a trivial operation. As expected the derivative of polynomial of 5th order (Linear) is a 3rd order polynomial.

##### From regressed coefficients

If fitted model is a polynomial, we can use regressed polynomial coefficients to deduce any order derivative.

```
Phat = np.poly1d(pipeline["model"].coef_[::-1])
Phat_xx = Phat.deriv(m=2)
```

Which can be use to interpolate new points:

```
yh_d2 = Phat_xx(np.squeeze(xlin))
```

This solution perfectly agrees with `yh_lin_d2`.

#### Proposal

Here is a complete proposal for having the second derivative based on a set of points that follow a polynomial trend:

```
def fit_diff(x, y, poly_order=5, resolution=200):
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ("transformer", PolynomialFeatures(poly_order)),
        ("model", LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))
    ])
    xlin = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), resolution).reshape(-1, 1)
    yhat = pipeline.fit(x, y).predict(xlin)
    dx = xlin[1, 0] - xlin[0, 0]
    dy2dx2 = signal.savgol_filter(yhat, 15, 3, deriv=2, delta=dx)
    return dy2dx2
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the numerical solution that @jlandercy has suggested, there is an analytical solution. Unfortunately, as I discussed in the comments, it's not a nice polynomial. For that reason, we need to bring in a new library, SymPy, which is capable of representing, simplifying, and differentiating arbitrary expressions.

I'm going to start by creating the same dataset he uses, to make the answers easier to compare.

```
import sympy as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(12345)
x_data = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
P = np.poly1d([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10])
y_data = P(x_data) + 0.5 * np.random.randn(x_data.size)
```

Then, fit a polynomial to a logged version of the data:

```
poly_coeffs = np.polyfit(x_data, np.log(y_data), deg=2)
```

Next, declare a variable X, and create a polynomial in terms of this variable. Raise it to the power of e.

```
x = sm.Symbol('x')
logged_poly = sm.Poly(poly_coeffs, x).as_expr()
non_logged_poly = sm.exp(logged_poly)
```

Next, take the second derivative of this expression with respect to x.

```
twice_diff = sm.diff(non_logged_poly, x, 2)
```

This gives us the expression

[image: differentiated expression]

Which is pretty ugly, but at least avoids the use of `np.gradient()` to find the second derivative.

Now, to use this in your code, you need to turn it back into a Python function. The SymPy function `lambdify()` can be used to do this.

```
f = sm.lambdify(x, twice_diff, 'numpy')
```

If you want to see the source code of the generated function, you can use `help(f)` to do so. (You don't need to copy this source code into your program. You can use `f()` directly. It's just to show what SymPy is doing internally.)

```
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return 9.99113566549129*(0.504928487945428*(x + 0.721464680150301)**2 + 0.710583202690176)*exp(x*(0.355291601345088*x + 0.512660683049044))
```

You can use this function either by passing one number at a time, or by passing an array of numbers.

```
f(0)
f(np.array([-1, 0, 1]))
```

If you want to plot the result of this function, you can do so like this:

```
plt.plot(x_data, f(x_data))
```